# Getting different number of rows both python and spark scala - dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, dataset

I'm trying to delete null values of some columns in dataframe but I'm getting different number of rows both python and scala.

I did the same for both. In python I receive **2127178** rows and scala i receive **8723** rows.

For example in python i did:

```
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["model"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["engine_type"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["aircraft_type"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["status"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["ArrDelay"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["issue_date"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["manufacturer"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["type"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["tailnum"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["DepDelay"], inplace= True)
dfplaneairport.dropna(subset=["TaxiOut"], inplace= True)

dfplaneairport.shape
(2127178, 32)
```

and spark scala i did:

```
dfairports = dfairports.na.drop(Seq("engine_type", "aircraft_type", "status", "model", "issue_date", "manufacturer", "type","ArrDelay", "DepDelay", "TaxiOut", "tailnum"))

dfairports.count()
8723
```

I am expecting the same number of rows and i'm don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not be using the [Pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna.html) `dropna` function, but the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) one. Notice the fact that you're using the `inplace` input argument whereas that does not exist in the Pyspark function.

Here are 2 bits of code (in Scala and in Pyspark) that behave exactly the same way.

Scala:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("James",null,"Smith","36636","M",3000), ("Michael","Rose",null,"40288","M",4000),
  ("Robert",null,"Williams","42114","M",4000),
  ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
  ("Jen","Mary","Brown",null,"F",-1)
).toDF("firstname", "middlename", "lastname", "id", "gender", "salary")
df.show                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|    James|      null|   Smith|36636|     M|  3000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|  Michael|      Rose|    null|40288|     M|  4000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|   Robert|      null|Williams|42114|     M|  4000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|39192|     F|  4000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown| null|     F|    -1|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+

df.na.drop(Seq("middlename", "lastname")).show                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|39192|     F|  4000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown| null|     F|    -1|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
```

Pyspark:

```
data = [("James",None,"Smith","36636","M",3000), ("Michael","Rose",None,"40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert",None,"Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown",None,"F",-1)
  ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["firstname", "middlename", "lastname", "id", "gender", "salary"])

df.show()
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|    James|      null|   Smith|36636|     M|  3000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|  Michael|      Rose|    null|40288|     M|  4000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|   Robert|      null|Williams|42114|     M|  4000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|39192|     F|  4000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown| null|     F|    -1|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+

df.dropna(subset=["middlename", "lastname"]).show()                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|39192|     F|  4000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown| null|     F|    -1|                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: Another question and sorry. How would i get the mode of a column using scala?

Comment: What do you mean by "mode of a column"?

Comment: the mode is the most frequently occurring value in a set of data, in this case a column

Comment: @WorkAll when you have another question popping up (like now), it's best to search on stack overflow whether the question has already been asked. If it hasn't, do start a new question post! I'll be happy to help when you make a new post :)